# Execute bash commands in .txt file via cronjob

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, cron

**Set-up**

I have 3 `.txt` files containing commands to be executed each day.

The `berlin_run.txt` file executes a.o. the 2 other `.txt` files. The file is the following,

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/folder/containing/berlin_run.txt
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

./spider_apartments_run.txt
./spider_rooms_run.txt
python berlin_apartments_ads.py;python berlin_rooms.py
```

When I `cd` to `/path/to/folder/containing/berlin_run.txt` in my MacOS Terminal, and execute the `./berlin_run.txt` command, everything works fine.

It is my understanding that `./` opens the `berlin_run.txt`, and that `#!/bin/bash` ensures that the subsequent lines in the `berlin_run.txt` are automatically executed upon opening.

---

**Problem**

I want to automate the execution of `berlin_run.txt`.

I have written the following cronjob,

```
10 13 * * * /path/to/folder/containing/berlin_run.txt
```

It is my understanding that this cronjob should open the `berlin_run.txt` each day at `13:10`. Assuming that is correct, `#!/bin/bash` should execute all the subsequent lines. But nothing seems to happen.

Where and what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is python in /usr/local/bin? or inside folders in PATH?

Comment: Not sure how I figure that out? Does it make a difference if it is/isn't? The code works fine when executed manually via Terminal.

Comment: `which python` is the command that let's you know where it is located.

Comment: just add `echo $PATH > /Users/youraccountname/path.txt` after `export PATH` in your script and see all the folders in the path. Now verify that the folder containing python is in the path.txt file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49296678/1135424 to help debug your cron

Comment: @Lino, if done the `which python` which shows `/Applications/anaconda/bin/python`. What should I do now?

Comment: Typically, a file containing a shell script would have a `.sh` extension.